# grep command to display only the two words searched for separated by a comma?

Tags: text-processing, grep

Say I have a file with the following text:

```
Hello there,
How are you?
```

How can I grep for `Hello` and `are` such that the output of `grep` looks like:

```
Hello,are
```

Comment: So you only want the words passed to `grep` to be included in the comma-separated output if they are in the contents of the file?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: You can't do it just with `grep`. You can pipe the output of `grep` to another command that combines the lines with commas between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
grep -Eo "Hello|are" file | sed '$!N;s/\n/,/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o "Hello\|are" test | tr '\n' ','
```

`-o` to only output matching strings, then replace `\n` with `,`.